# String comparison looping function from interview

Tags: powershell

Input should be a string and an integer J. The function needs to print out the string as entered, but if a character is the same as any of the last J characters, put a X in between.

1. `DoSomething("AA",2)` should output `AXXA`; needs to have 2 characters printed before it prints the same one.
2. `DoSomething("ABB",2)` should output `ABXXB`
3. `DoSomething("ABABA",3)` should output `ABXXABXXA`.

I tried doing this in PowerShell first:

```
DoSomething -string 'AA' -cool 3
```

Should output AXXXA

```
DoSomething -string 'AB' -cool 3
```

Should output AB

```
DoSomething -string 'ABA' -cool 3
```

Should output ABXXA

```
DoSomething -string 'AA' -cool 1
```

Should output AXA

```
DoSomething -string 'ABC' -cool 1
```

Should output ABC

```
DoSomething -string 'AAA' -cool 2
```

Should output AXXAXXA

Comment: Please edit your question to be more readable. Use the code formatting available in the editor to help make it legible. I tried to edit it for you but the code just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, some of the wording of the problem definition is unclear

Comment: Pretty sure you need to actually include some code here.

Comment: What's the question here? What have you tried on your own? What's the application of this, other than attempting to answer an arbitrary question from an interview?

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I hate interviews, while it is a relatively easy question. I had to sit down and think it through for a little while, to simulate trying to answer with just notepad. Note the trick here is that you only need to check and compare the last `val` number of characters at any point in time.

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var chr in PrintWithRepeatRule("ABABA",3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(chr);
    }
}
IEnumerable<char> PrintWithRepeatRule(string str, int val)
{
    var charList = new List<char>();
    foreach(var chr in str)
    {

        for(int i =val-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if(charList.Count < 1)
                continue;           
            var cnt = charList.Count - i-1 ;
            if (cnt < 0 || charList.Count< cnt)
                continue;
            if(charList[cnt] ==chr)
            {
                for(int j =0; j<(val-i);j++)
                    charList.Add('-');

            }
        }
        charList.Add(chr);
    }
    return charList;
}
```